# Nextion Dual State Button

Tags: arduino-mega, arduino-ide, lcd, tft

I am having an issue with my Nextion display. I have uploaded the following code via Arduino IDE to my Arduino MEGA 2560.

My Nextion Editor shows the button as `ID:9` on `page0` named `floor`. I am not entirely sure if the code below is correct. I had one issue where the upload from the laptop to the Mega wouldn't finish, but I managed to bypass that issue by disconnecting the Nextion and swapping RX and TX cables from Nextion while the upload was in progress. Not sure how else I would fix that issue? (If anyone has any ideas haha)

All that is meant to happen is when the dual button state is changed, the onboard `LED_BUILTIN` is set to `HIGH` and if in its second state, is set to `LOW`.

## CODE

```
#include "Nextion.h"


NexDSButton bt0 = NexDSButton(0, 9, "floor");


int ledPin = LED_BUILTIN;


char buffer[100] = {0};


NexTouch *nex_listen_list[] = 
{
    &bt0,
    NULL
};



void bt0PopCallback(void *ptr)
{
    uint32_t dual_state;
    NexDSButton *btn = (NexDSButton *)ptr;
    dbSerialPrintln("b0PopCallback");
    dbSerialPrint("ptr=");
    dbSerialPrintln((uint32_t)ptr); 
    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

    if(dual_state) 
    {
        digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    }
    else
    {
        digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    }
}

void setup(void)
{    
    nexInit();

    bt0.attachPop(bt0PopCallback, &bt0);
    
    dbSerialPrintln("setup done"); 
    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop(void)
{   
    nexLoop(nex_listen_list);
}
```

My issue is that the MEGA is identifying the touch event (as the TX LED on the MEGA flashes) however it is not turning on the MEGA's onboard built-in LED.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you select a hardware serial port for nexSerial? Do you see the text "setup done"? Do you see the text "b0PopCallback"? Did you enable the event in the nextion editor? Please update your initial question with more information.

Comment: I have done no coding in the Nextion editor as I thought Arduino IDE handles all the coding. How would I go about enabling the event in Nextion?

Comment: I will admit that I did load this code from a sample sketch provided by Nextion, however I ONLY used the code and never looked into the .HMI file. I might browse over that and try and understand what you mean by enabling the event in Nextion :)

Comment: In the callback, where does it assign a value to dual_state?

Answer (score 1):

This is part of the code I have been using for an extraction fan, The button text is tested and if the button matches the command the fan is turned on or off and the button text is changed accordingly. Hope this helps.

```
void b19PopCallback(void *ptr) //Extraction Fan
{
  NexButton *btn = (NexButton *)ptr;
  memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
  btn->getText(buffer, sizeof(buffer));

  if (strcmp(buffer, "ON"))
  {
    //COMES BACK AS A FALSE (0) IF BOTH STRINGS MATCH
    digitalWrite(b_motor, LOW);
    strcpy(buffer, "ON");
    btn->setText(buffer);
  }

  else 
  {
    digitalWrite(b_motor, HIGH);
    strcpy(buffer, "OFF");
    btn->setText(buffer);
  }  

}
```

Comment: `strcmp` doesn't return `true` or `false` so your comment about it returning FALSE if both strings match is a bit misleading. See [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) - `strcmp` is designed to return a number < 0 if string1 is less than string2, 0 if they are the same, and > 0 if string1 is greater than string2 (in the collating sequence).

Comment: Regardless of the failure in describing the return type of strcmp, I believe that is indeed what the OP is missing.  The code in OP never checks the string and assign any value to dual_state.

Answer (score 1):

You can try int ledPin=13 instead of led_builtin . Led builtin connected 13 pin. Most Arduinos have an on-board LED you can control. On the UNO, MEGA and ZERO it is attached to digital pin 13 .  Try  this one.

```
#include "Nextion.h"
int ledPin = 13;
NexDSButton bt0 = NexDSButton(0, 1, "bt0");
uint32_t dual_state=0;

void setup(){
nexInit();
pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}
void loop(){
bt0.getValue(&dual_state);
delay(200);

if(dual_state==1) //When pressed dual state button dual_state =1
  {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  }
  else if(dual_state==0)
  {
    digitalWrite(ledPin,LOW ); 
  }

}
```